# SharePoint loop to next item

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have several items in a custom list. I have a Site Workflow that will check each item for criteria before moving that item to another list.

Currently, in order for the workflow to move to the next item I need to delete the item. How do I get the workflow to cycle through each item?